# If you mix the anode and cathode in a electrolyte solution you will have a short-circuit?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

So, I just saw [this video](https://youtu.be/0Jm2FR5A3Hk) a person makes a rechargeable copper-zinc battery in an epsom salt electrolyte solution where the zinc and copper are two metal plates.

If you, for some reason, took copper powder and zinc powder and mixed with the electrolyte solution, will you have a short-circuit or just some kind of "liquid battery"?

Comment: how would you connect the battery to a load, such as a lightbulb?

Comment: For certain batteries, such a mixture would cause a RUD, a Rapid Unscheduled Disassembly. The electrolyte isn't necessary, but the anode and cathode materials, usually separated by high electronegativity, love to exchange electrons directly, not through a circuit.

Comment: In other words, if I understand this correctly, by mixing certain chemicals together you simply get what is known as a *chemical reaction*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll end up with a soup of tiny voltage cells, that are randomly arranged in polarity with no way to connect to the anode or cathode, because they are swirling around in the soup.

When you use two metal plates (copper and zinc), all the copper is together and all the zinc is together, so all the molecules are arranged together for each metal, thus all in the same polarity.  This allows you to separate all the copper from the zinc with the electrolyte and it also allows you to connect/contact the copper and zinc with separate wires, which in turn allows you to harness the moving electrons.
  Voila - a battery cell.

Comment: Voila!, or, perhaps, Volta!

Answer (score 7):

[Liquid-metal batteries](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=liquid+metal+battery) do exist, but these operate at high (molten salt usually) temperatures and are currently still being researched.  They are impractical for most roles due to their high heat requirement and exotic construction.

Adding any conductive metal powder to any (other, standard, room-temperature) battery chemistry is a recipe for physically shorting the anodes and cathodes.  At least temporarily, if/until the electrolyte can dissolve the free metal.  This may depend on how "charged" each cell is.  If it can dissolve the free metal, the cell might "open up again" but now this excess dissolved metal might have to be plated out or converted to something else.  Generally, if the metal is the *same* as the anode or cathode, it is plated out (by charging.)  But a *different* metal than the anode or cathode is usually considered a contaminant, and will likely be detrimental to operation by forming incompatible compounds.  The details of this can exceed an entire degree in [electrochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemistry), and is why battery development takes decades.

For lots of general information on battery types, charging, performance, and maintenance, see [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com).

Answer (score 5):

You will most probably get exactly what you imagine - a high number of short-circuits wherever some copper particle and some zinc particle touch.

Of course, you will get no usable electricity from the mixture. You will get heat instead.

p.s. if you are curious: this is how the electrochemical corrosion works. Some contaminant as a second electrode and water as an electrolyte.